# Pass a script function to another html script page

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage

So for example I have this function

```
function Payment() {
  var name = document.getElementByID("name").value;
  alert(name);
}

localStorage.setItem("Payment", Payment());
```

How can I do that, is it possible?

Comment: Your code sets `Payment` to `undefined`, as the `Payment` function doesn't return anything. That said, you can't store functions in `localStorage`.

Comment: No you can't store function. What you can do is store a string key and then call function from that key.

Comment: Like this, you're storing Payment's result (undefined), not the function itself. You can't store a function directly, however, you can store its code and eval it later. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAIK, localStorage can't store functions. However, you can store the code and eval it later.

```js
function Payment() {
  var name = document.getElementByID("name").value;
  alert(name);
}

// store Payment or Payment.toString()
// storing Payment() is storing the function's result
localStorage.setItem("Payment", Payment.toString())
```

Then later...

```js
const StoredPayment = eval('(' + localStorage.getItem("Payment") + ')');

StoredPayment();
```

Comment: is giving me this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> ((index):6), <anonymous>:2:53)
    at (index):46

Comment: Seems you're passing a null somewhere along the way.... Pls post more code.

Comment: the problem is that when try to call the localStorage in another page I dont have there the  values properties

Comment: I think `localStorage` should work under the same origin (basically the same domain), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin

Comment: Storing function string and using eval() is dangerous because the user can modify the function and call any code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: @user2258152, I agree, however, the end user can modify and run anything he wants on frontend :-)

Comment: I also agree :) hmmm but what about if a third party app read all localStorage and inject code in hoping that a script use eval() while reading the string from localStorage ?

Answer (score 1):

Store the function name and read it from the other script to call the function. The other script must contain the function.

Include in both script or only in the second script if you don't use it at all in the first script.

```
const obj = {
  payment: () => {
    var name = document.getElementByID('name').value
    alert(name)
  }
}
```

First script (set function name you want to store)

```
localStorage.setItem('func', 'payment')
```

Second script (get function name and call it)

```
const funcName = localStorage.getItem('func')

// Call function
obj[funcName]()
```

Note: Using eval() is the solution if you don't want to duplicate your code but I think it's very dangerous because the user can modify the function in localStorage and execute any code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: You still need to pass `obj` across pages to satisfy this question...

Comment: Yes you need to duplicate the obj or function on the other page

Comment: so in the other page do i need to duplicate the 

Store the function name and read it from the other script to call the function. The other script must contain the function.

const obj = {
  payment: () => {
    var name = document.getElementByID('name').value
    alert(name)
  }
}

Comment: Actually, the first script does not actually need the function if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your function as `string` into `localStorage` and can reuse it using `eval` function.

To store the function into `localStorage`

```
function Payment() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  console.log(name);
  alert(name);
}
localStorage.setItem('func', Payment.toString());
```

To get the function date from localStorage.

```
localStorage.getItem('func');
```

Attached shows how to call the stringified function.

```js
var payment = `function Payment() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  console.log(name);
  alert(name);
}`;

eval(payment);
Payment();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" value="hello" />
```